# How to replicate big transactional tables with IBM InfoSphere CDC?

Tags: replication, informix, database-replication, cdc, ibm-data-replication

I have a big transactional table with 80,000,000 records and about 1,000 tps in informix. How can I replicate it without losing data?

-using load/unload for skipping refresh before mirror end with data loss

-using refresh before mirror, stops the subscription after replicating 12,000,000 records with 242 sql error number.

Answer (score 1):

There is a procedure to do that, using commands dmmarkexternalunloadstart and dmmarkexternalunloadend.  I think these are the only two commands that cannot be executed through GUI (Management Console). Try the following procedure for external replication:

1) Invoke the command on the source system to mark the starting point of the Refresh (for each table):

dmmarkexternalunloadstart –I  –s  –t

2) Start refreshing the table(s)

dmrefresh –I  -a –s  [–t ]

3) When the Refresh has completed, mark the end point of the Refresh for each table

dmmarkexternalunloadend –I  –s  –t

4) Start Mirroring the changes for the table that was just refreshed.

dmstartmirror –I  -n –s